# What is mean by 'server','instance' in MSSQLServer 2005

Tags: sql-server-2005

IN MS SQLSERVER 2005 I cannot understand the following terms

server

instance

Answer (score 12, accepted):

A *server* is a (physical or virtual) machine hosting SQL Server software.

An *instance* is a collection of SQL Server databases run by a single SQL Server service, ahem, instance. You can view each separate instance you're running in your service console. Each instance can be started or stopped individually.

You're meant to use instances to partition data and policies. Each instance has completely separate databases, connection configuration, and security credentials.

Answer (score 1):

If there are multiple server installations on single machine they are identified by instance name. In your connection string use format `{server}\{instance}` for non-default instances.

Answer (score 0):

An instance is an Environment which is used to Create a Multiple Database and connect to the Application server through an interface to retrieve the data from Backend to the Application for Enduser.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen a nice explanation from [Reddit](https://www.quora.com/What-is-SQL-Server-Instance) by Brandon Leach that

> Since SQL Server is software like any other, you can have multiple
> installations. Both installations can be running on the same box at
> the same time. Say I have a server called “`Server1`″ and two instances
> called “`Instance1`” and “`Instance2`″. In order to access Instance1 in my
> connection string I would use “`Server1\Instance2`” as my server name.
> Instance1 in our scenario was installed first so it is the default
> instance, meaning I can just use “`Server1`” as my server name.

Answer (score -3):

What is "an instance" of a server?

The body of design for (a) coded function(s) is called a "CLASS".

To use the designed elements, coding, and functionality of a class, you need to build (define) a housing for it called an "OBJECT".

Thus the "OBJECT" is an "instance" (real thing) of a "Class" (only a design, no substance).

It's like a blueprint is a plan to build a house, say... and when you build the house, it is an instance of the plan.  Thus the plan is the class, and the house is the object.

Bottom Line:
A Server (class) must be "instantiated" to create an actual working Server "object"
which is a set of working functions to manage and deal with stored data.  (see Tables, elsewhere)

Comment: This is an answer from a programming perspective, not a database perspective.